# Get all types from nested generics in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

Let's say I have following classes.

```
class Person {
    var name: String?
}

class DataParser<T: AnyObject> {
    var result: T?
}

class PersonParser<T: Person> : DataParser<Person> { }
```

Now, I would like to create another class that instanciates sublasses of `DataParser`, according to the passed template type.

```
class ParserFactory<T: DataParser<AnyObject>> {
    var result: AnyObject?
}
```

It is OK, but there may be a better way. The result is `AnyObject`, although we know that if the passed generic type was `PersonParser`, the result would have been a `Person`.
What I want to do, is to adapt the class so I can get the *nested* generic type of the passed generic as result type, so that the compiler gives me the right object type.

I tried to write this code, but of course, it does not compile. But at least you will get what I'm trying to do.

```
class ParserFactory<T: DataParser<U: AnyObject>> {
    var result: U?
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create protocol:

   ```
   protocol A {
       typealias ItemType
   }
   ```
2. Conform your class to the protocol:

   ```
   class DataParser<T: AnyObject>: A {
       typealias ItemType = T

       var result: ItemType?
   }
   ```
3. Use your nested generic type inside your another class:

   ```
   class ParserFactory<T: A> {
       var result: T.ItemType?
   }
   ```
4. Check if it is working:

   ```
   let parserFactory = ParserFactory<DataParser<Person>>()

   print(parserFactory.result.dynamicType) //Person
   ```